# Convert decimal to binary in ruby

Tags: ruby, binary

I am trying to convert a decimal to binary, so I came up with this:

```
print "Enter decimal here: "
decimal = gets.chomp
puts decimal.to_s(2)
#>> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
#>> (repl):3:in 'to_s'
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decimal` comes from `stdin` as a string. And `String#to_s` does not accept arguments. You should do instead:

```
puts decimal.to_i.to_s(2)
```